# Javascript - discount sum

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with my code.
I should have 2 boxes for pricees
And if sum is below 50  a message show SUM is xx - "no discount."
if between 50-300 message show SUM is xx - "10% discount"
if 300 or more message show SUM is xx - "20% discount"

I just can´t get this work. Also i want the third input to be closed so no input could be inserted.

````
```

<script>
  function myCalculator(a,b){

    var c=parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
    document.getElementById('text').value = c;

    if ( c >= 100 {
      text="no discount less than 100!";
    }
    else if (c<100 && total) 500 ) {
      text= "total=(a+b), 10% doscount. New price xx";
    }
    else if (c<500) {
      text= "total=(a+b), 20% doscount. New price xx";
    }
</script>

<h1>BUY</h1>
<input type="text" value="" id="text1"></input> +
<input type="text" value="" id="text2"></input> =
<input type="text" value="" id="text3"></input>
<input type="button" value="TOTALPRICE" 
 onclick='myCalculator(document.getElementById("text1").value,
 document.getElementById("text2").value)'></input>
````

Comment: Check the browser's development console.  Your code is full of syntax errors.  Your first steps should be to correct those errors, ensure that your HTML and JavaScript are both valid (there are free validators available online, use your favorite search engine), then test your code.  After you've corrected your syntax errors and formatted your code clearly and consistenty, if it still fails then you begin investigating the problem.  When you get stuck in that investigation, we can help with that.

Comment: also you've inverted your `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have syntax issue in script
- you're not printing the text
- you're not calculating the discounted value.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euq32g97/4/)

```
function myCalculator(a, b) {
  var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  var text = '';
  document.getElementById('text3').value = c;
  if (c < 50) {
      text = "no discount less than 50!";
  }
  else if (c >= 50 && c <= 300) {
      text = "total=(a+b), 10% doscount. New price: " + Math.round(c * 0.9);
  }
  else if (c > 300) {
      text = "total=(a+b), 20% doscount. New price:" + Math.round(c * 0.8);
  }
  document.getElementById('text4').innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there were a lot of errors in your code but I corrected them. You need to be careful while defining ids' of tags. If you have any questions about the corrected version of the code, you can ask whenever you want.

```
    <h1>BUY</h1>
    <input type="number" value="" id="text1"></input> + 
    <input type="number" value="" id="text2"></input> = 
    <input type="text" value="" id="text3"></input>
    <input type="button" value="TOTALPRICE" onclick='myCalculator();'></input>
<script>
    function myCalculator(){
      let c= parseInt(document.getElementById("text1").value);
      let d = parseInt(document.getElementById("text2").value);
      let sum = c + d;
      document.getElementById('text3').value = sum;
      if ( sum < 50) {
          window.alert("Your total is " + sum + ". No discount less than 50!");
      }
      else if (sum <= 300 && sum > 50 ) {
          let newPrice = sum * 0.9;
          window.alert("Your total is " + sum + ". 10% discount. New price is " + newPrice);
      }
      else if (sum > 300) {
          let newPrice = sum * 0.8;
          window.alert("Your total is " + sum + ". 20% discount. New price is " + newPrice);
      }
    }
</script>
```